# Convert Haml to HTML without evaluating inline Ruby script

Tags: ruby, haml

I need to convert Haml scripts to their equivalent HTML scripts. As I'm doing this outside and without running the main rails project, the Ruby scripts present in the Haml files are throwing exceptions (which is obvious). Now, I won't mind if the Ruby script is present in the output HTML (in that case it'll look like an erb, that's fine for me). I'm concerned with some html tags only.

It seems like if I can override `Haml::Engine#render(scope = Object.new, locals = {}, &block)` method then it could help. But not getting it fully.

Any idea?

**Update**

Converting only `-` foo and `=` foo blocks into Erb `<% foo %>` and `<%= foo %>` (respectively) won't work completely, because interpolation will be there, like:

`%div{:class => "#{cycle("cssClass1", "cssClass2")} anotherCssClass"}`

The acceptable output for my case can be:
`<div class=<%= "#{cycle("cssClass1", "cssClass2")} anotherCssClass" %> ></div>`

Other than those interpolations [this](https://gist.github.com/17371) works well for `-` and `=`.

Comment: Can you please provide a simple sample Haml file and the output you want to get? Do you want Ruby `- foo` and `= foo` blocks to turn into Erb `<% foo %>` and `<%= foo %>` (respectively), or something else?

Comment: @Phrogz Thanks for your response. I've updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: That's good extra information, but not enough (for me). Please provide the full text of a minimal Haml file covering edge cases you are worried about and the full output you want.

Comment: Isn't the question really about HAML -> ERB conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into the [HAML to ERB converter gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/haml2erb)?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't find it somehow.

Comment: No worries. Glad to have helped.